# What is the difference between a SharePoint Specialist, Consultant and Engineer?

Tags: function

What is the difference between these job functions: SharePoint Specialist vs SP Consultant vs SP Engineer?

I am really confused and which one pays better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These job titles are mostly meaningless. They are used by HR types and recruiters and have no bearing on the work people actually do.

The people who get paid the most will be the people who have the strongest track records, who live in the strongest job markets, and who have are the best salary negotiators.